# How to allow WebAssembly in Firefox for specific websites only

Tags: firefox, about-config

In Mozilla Firefox's `about:config`, I have disabled WebAssembly by setting `javascript.options.wasm` to `false`. However, there are some trusted websites where I want to allow WebAssembly. How do I define a whitelist to enable WebAssembly in specific websites only, while disabling WebAssembly for all other websites?

Firefox version: 115.6.0esr. OS: Debian 12.